# “mcar: expects argument of type <mutable-pair>; given ()” in member-like function

Tags: list, function, scheme, boolean, racket

```
(define fun3
  (lambda (item list) 
    (cond ((equal? item (car list))) 
          ((fun3 item (cdr list)))
          (else #f))))
```

I want to know what is wrong if I enter an element which is not in the list. There it show an error.`--mcar: expects argument of type <mutable-pair>; given ()`

Comment: I enter (fun3 'w (list 'a 'b )) to execute this , But it show error as mentioned. Other wise if it found the element, then no error.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/664288/1281433.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you get to the end of your list? A list like `(1 2 3)` is actually a chain of cons cells:

```
(1 2 3) == (1 . (2 . (3 . ())))
```

You get the thing on the left side of the `.` using `car`, and the thing on the right using `cdr`.  Consider what happens when you search for `4` in `(1 2 3)` with your code:

```
(define fun3
  (lambda (item list) 
    (cond ((equal? item (car list))) 
          ((fun3 item (cdr list)))
          (else #f))))
```

Eventually you recurse to the case where `item` is (still) `4`, and `list` is `(3 . ())`.  Now, `(fun3 item (cdr list))` will be called, and then `item` will (still) be `4`, but `list` will be `()`.  You can't call `(car ())` because `()` isn't a cons cell.  You need to explicitly check the case that `list` is the empty list:

```
(define fun3
  (lambda (item list) 
    (cond ((null? list) <...>)
          ((equal? item (car list))) 
          ((fun3 item (cdr list)))
          (else #f))))
```

Now, there are two things to note:

1. This can be simplified significantly.  Using some boolean logic, you could even get rid of the `cond` entirely (see [Scheme, search if a word is a part of list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19349749/1281433) for some ideas about how).    The general point here is that you're doing something analogous to the C code

   ```
   if ( condition ) {
     return false;
   }
   else {
     return true;
   }
   ```

   which can be simplified greatly to `return !condition;`.  Do you see how your code is similar to that?  Particularly, your second case is `(fun3 item (cdr list))`.  If it's true, then you return true.  If it's false, then you go to the next case and… return false.  This means you can simply return the value of `(fun3 item (cdr list))`.
2. The more important issue is that you said you wanted to check whether `item` is an element of a list *or any of its sublists*, but your code right now (pending the fix about checking for the empty list) only checks whether `item` is a member of `list`, not any of its sublists.  When `item` isn't equal to `(car list)`, it could be because `(car list)` is another list, and you'll need to recurse into to and check whether `item` is in it.   You might be helped by looking at [search through nested list in scheme to find a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9442236/1281433), but it won't tell you *exactly* how to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. Got my fault. Will keep in mind.

Answer (score 0):

In case you use mutable lists/pairs in racket, you have to keep in mind that it's completely separate data type from regular lists, where you use the () syntax.
When you 'request' the library for working with mutable data by calling:
    (request scheme/mpair)
You now have to switch to using corresponding procedures from that lib - mcar, mcdr, mpair, mlist, mcons when constructing the pair, predicates, etc. Otherwise there's no way to receive and error from 'mcons'.
http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/mpairs.html